# Is it possible to us SpEL to inject constant in @Query annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[SpEL](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language) Spring Exp, I am aware that we can just use the concatenation operator `+` so constants are evaluated.

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE kdo set is_revise=0, update_by="
  + Constant.CREATOR+ ", update_time= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where kdo.id=:kdoId", nativeQuery = true)
int flagRevised(String kdoId);
```

But I am curious that it can be done using Spring Expression Langage. As somehow already demonstrated [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions). But in my case, I want to use constant, my method only needs 1 parameter.

Comment: I'm just thinking, maybe this would work (haven't tested): `:#{${T(com.example.app.ConstantClass).CONSTANT_IT_IS}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: many `SpEL` expressions are not implemented/supported with [`nativeQuery`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions).

###### If you forgo `nativeQuery` and use `JPQL`, you can add a SpEL expression instead of a constant in your query like this:

`..., update_by=:#{T(x.y.z.Constant).CREATOR}, ...`

`OR`

`..., update_by=?#{T(x.y.z.Constant).CREATOR}, ...`

*(The actual SpEL expression binding is either triggered by ?# or :#.)*

###### If you can't give up `nativeQuery` but are using (or can use) `Spring Data JPA` later than `3.0.0` you can use [`QueryRewriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-rewriter).

> QueryRewriter:
>
> Sometimes, no matter how many features you try to apply, it seems
> impossible to get Spring Data JPA to apply every thing you’d like to a
> query before it is sent to the EntityManager.
>
> With 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT (and targeted for the next milestone release train
> of Spring Data), you now have the ability to get your hands on the
> query, right before it’s sent to the EntityManager and “rewrite” it.
> That is, you can make any alterations at the last moment.

We can have the query pass through the `SpelExpressionParser` so that this `QueryRewriter` recognizes the `SpEL` statements. ***(Different problems may require `TemplateParserContext` or more code improvements.)***

Let's create our `SpELQueryRewriter` class:

```java
public class SpELQueryRewriter implements QueryRewriter {

    @Override
    public String rewrite(String query, Sort sort) {
        ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        TemplateParserContext templateParserContext = new TemplateParserContext();
        Expression expression = expressionParser
                .parseExpression(query, templateParserContext);
        return (String) expression.getValue();
    }
}
```

Let's add our `SpEL` expression and qqq class for `Constant.CREATOR` contant:

```java
@Query(value = "UPDATE kdo "
                + "SET is_revise=0, "
                    + "update_by='#{T(x.y.z.Constant).CREATOR}', "
                    + "update_time= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP "
                + "WHERE kdo.id=:kdoId",
        nativeQuery = true,
        queryRewriter = SpELQueryRewriter.class)
int flagRevised(String kdoId);
```

Your query will look like this:

```sql
UPDATE kdo SET is_revise=0, update_by='CREATOR', update_time= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE kdo.id=:kdoId
```